# Call Same Class Constructor Using same Class Method in Java

Tags: java

How can I call same `class` constructor from same class method?
 I can use `this()` but it raise the error.

```
class MyConstructor {
    public MyConstructor() {
        System.out.println("My Constructor") ;
    }
    public void MyCall () {
        // Call MyConstructor
    }
}

public class Constructor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyConstructor mycon = new MyConstructor() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error/problem?

Comment: If the method is called, then the object is already constructed. You can't construct the object from a method of that object. You can create another instance, though: new MyConstructor().

Comment: what do you mean call the constructor? it is to create an object.what is the call supposed to do when obj is already created?

Comment: Exactly what do you hope to achieve by "calling the constructor"?

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the constructor when instantiating a new Object with the new()-Keyword.It is not possible to call the constructor from within the class otherwise. But you can write another function whit all the logic from the constructor-MEthod. In the constructor you just call this method.

```
    class MyConstructor {

    public MyConstructor() {
       helperMethod();
    }

    public void helperMethod(){
     System.out.println("My Constructor") ;
    }


public void MyCall () {
    // Call MyConstructor   
   helperMethod();   
}
```